# ASP.NET & MySql

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server

I've recently published my WebApp on the web.
I noticed my ISP provided me a plan with 10MB MSSql Express, Would it be enough to store data from 3 busy shops? However, they did not limit the size of an MySql Database.

Would you suggest me to connect my webapp to an MySql db instead? How is it possible using Visual Studio?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about the size of 10 Megabytes? This is a very low capacity

Comment: That's what they mention on their hosting plans, 1 MS-SQL Express db (10MB).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type and amount of data you'd want to store in the DB.

You can have your .NET application talk to MySQL using MySQL Connector/net: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Note, however, that there are syntax (and other) differences between MSSQL and MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. 
which is more stable / can store more data? MSSQL or MySql?

Comment: I don't have .NET experience in production systems. I worked with Connector/net in a couple of small desktop applications and it was fine. If you're asking about the DB itself then both are robust database systems. If you're a ".NET guy" and the entire project is in .NET then, costs aside, it makes sense to go with MSSQL. Regarding storage capacity - I'm not sure what the absolute physical limit would be but  both should be more than sufficient for any requirements you might have.